# what does "a wff f(x, y)" mean exactly? (context: transfinite recursion)

Tags: logic, set-theory

I'm currently working through Herbert B. Enderton's book "Elements of set theory". I have a question concerning notation in logic, of which I know the basics but in which I'm not that firmly grounded. It is essential that I understand exactly what he means by his notation and I hope that this is an easy one for those who know.

On page 177 the Transfinite Recursion Theorem Schema is stated as follows:

For any formula $\gamma(x, y)$ the following is a theorem:
Assume that $<$ is a well ordering on a set $A$. Assume that for any $f$ there is a unique $y$ such that $\gamma(f,y)$. Then tere exists a unique function $F$ with domain $A$ such that $\gamma(F \big | seg(t), F(t)) $ for all $t$ in $A$. Here $seg(t)=\{ x \in A \colon x<t \}$.

Now to my question:
Am I right in my assumption that he means that $\gamma(x, y)$ be a first order formula in the language of set theory such that $x $ and $y$ occur freely in it and such that $ \Gamma \models  (\forall x) (\exists!y) \gamma(x, y)$, where $\Gamma$ is the set of axioms in ZFC?

Similarly on page 179 when he introduces the Replacement axiom:

Replacement axioms: For any formula $\varphi(x,y) $ not containing the letter $B$, the following is an axiom:
$ \forall A [(\forall x \in A) \forall y_1 \forall y_2 (\varphi(x,y_1) \& \varphi(x,y_2) \implies y_1=y_2) \implies \exists B \forall y(y \in B  \iff (\exists x \in A)\varphi(x,y))]  $

Am I to understand that $\varphi(x,y) $ is any wff in which x and y occur freely (and in which there is no $B$)? Is $\varphi$ allowed to contain any other variables?

Comment: Yes: your "reading" of $\gamma(x,y)$ is correct. In general, in the "current" use of $\varphi(x,y)$ neither means that the listed variables occur free nor that no other ones occur free.

Comment: Thank you very much (again)!